How to work with logcat's messages?
Every time I interact with logcat, I am spammed with a lot of uninteresting debug messages from all over the system. How do Android developers narrow down its output, so that they can focus on that single application they're currently debugging?

Possibly related/dupe: How to get adb logcat to filter ONLY by specific app (package name)

None of the existing solutions satisfied my needs. So I wrote a utility logcatx.
